# jQuery multiplying two divs within jquery

Tags: jquery

I've been at it for hours trying to figure out how to get a jQuery function to multiply the quantity box in magento along with the price. This is what i have so far:

```
$('.add-to-cart.bottom .input-text').blur(function () {
    var a = $('input[name="qty"]').html();
    var b = $('#product-price-11_clone.span.price').html().replace("$", "");
    $.jGrowl("Lifeline Bands <br />Quantity: " + $(this).val() + "<br />Estimated Cost:" + $('.total').html(parseInt(a) * parseInt(b));
    });
```

I've been pulling my hairs for hours, can anyone please help? I'm using jGrowl and i just need the display box to show the multiplication of the quantity box with price.

Comment: Proper formatting makes the code easier to read and already shows you where you might have syntax errors. There is a reason why the last line (`});`) is indented that way. Chrome shows `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;`. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Comment: Have yout tried forcing parsing base: $('.total').html(parseInt(a,10) *parseInt(b,10)? BTW, what is the problem/error???

Comment: `console.log(a, b)` will tell you what each var contains, making it way easier to debug

Comment: Always specify the radix when using `parseInt()`, it's easy to miss a bug caused by this statement.

Comment: Also, you haven't explained your problem at all. What happens and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @roasted The problem is its not getting the value of the input box and the price within the <span> and multiplying it to get the final value.

Comment: So, is the jGrowl box shown but with the wrong value? Or what happens?

Comment: Basically im trying to have jGrowl show this:
Lifeline Bands<br />
Quantity 200<br />
Estimated Cost: (Value would be Quantity Multiplied Price Box which is span.price)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var a = $('input[name="qty"]').val();
```

Is `#product-price-11_clone.span.price` also an `<input>` element? If it is a `<span>`, use `.html()`.

Comment: Yeah it is a <span> but it contains a dollar amount. Which is why i used the .replace() on that certain field.

Comment: Then change the method in the `var a=...` statement to val. Print a and b to the log and see whether the expected values are printed.

Answer (score 0):

Here I got your problem:

```
var a = $('input[name="qty"]').html();
```

In the above line your selector show that it is a textfield.
So you need to change it with `.val();`

Like this:

```
var a = $('input[name="qty"]').val();
```